# Loop jumps one element

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm writing a function that breaks down change into denominations and returns the updated register after change has been given. So far it's working but only if the register has enough money in the respective denominations. If the change is `[ 10, 4, 0.5, 0.05 ]` as in this case and there are no 10 dollar bills in the register for example, the loop should move on to 5 dollar bills and check if change can be given from those and so on. But what it does instead is it jumps right to 1 dollar bills. What am I missing here? As for indexes, those are pre-calculated in my greater function, so `10` starts going through the loop at index `2` since all denominations before that are greater than `10`, `4` starts looping at index `4` since that is the index of 1 dollar bills in the cash register, and so on.

```js
let change = [ 10, 4, 0.5, 0.05 ]
let denomin = [ 100, 20, 10, 5, 1, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01 ]
let register = [ 100, 60, 0, 55, 90, 4.25, 3.1, 2.05, 1.01 ]
let idx = [ 2, 4, 5, 7 ]

function test(ch, reg, idx) {
    for (let x of ch) {
        for (let i = idx[ch.indexOf(x)]; i < reg.length; i++) {
            if (reg[i] - x >= 0) {
                reg[i] -= x
                break;
            } else if (reg[i] - x < 0) {
                i++
            }
        }
    }
    return reg = reg.map(a => Number(a.toFixed(2)))
}

console.log(test(change, register, idx))
```

Comment: Be careful using floats to represent currency. `0.1 + 0.2` will give you slightly more than 30 cents.  Use `100` to represent a dollar instead of `1`

Comment: Don't use floating point for this. Do everything as integer pennies rather than fractional dollars.

Comment: Thank you but is that what's causing the loop to jump one element?

Comment: In your else you have `i++` but that is already taken care of by the for loop running its next iteration.  Result - it skips 2.

Comment: @James should i just leave it blank then?

Comment: You have `i++` in your else block, it will cause this skip

Comment: Yes I think you can delete the whole else if clause.

Comment: @James thank you! That fixed it. Less code, too xD